# How can i verify existence signature in replying Outlook MailItem?

Tags: c#, outlook, mailitem

I have a mail (.msg), and i need to reply it. If user didn't set a signature for **reply** messages in Outlook, i'm creating default signature and appending it to a message body later.

```
public static MailItem CreateReplyMail(string mailPath, out string signature) {
        signature = string.Empty;
        try {
            if(File.Exists(mailPath)) {
                Application outlook = new Application();
                var item = outlook.Session.OpenSharedItem(mailPath) as MailItem;
                var replyMail = item.ReplyAll();
                Inspector inspector = replyMail.GetInspector;
                inspector.Activate();                                                       

                return replyMail;
            }
            return null;
        } catch(COMException e) {
            //...
        }
    }
```

How can i verify existence signature in replying Outlook MailItem?
After inspector.Activate() in replyMail.Body i always have auto-generated text and signature, if user set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Document.Bookmarks.Exists("_MailAutoSig")`.